# 5 minute edit grace period not applied?

Tags: bug, edits

This question ([How to save program work data in JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74069381)) was [edited twice](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74069381/timeline) within five minutes after posting:

> [image: Post Timeline]

These edits show up in the history, despite taking place within five minutes after posting and without any comments being posted.

Shouldn't revisions done within five minutes of each other be collapsed into one? Or were comments removed after each edit?

Comment: I can't find an MSO dupe for this (and I don't feel like searching on MSE, but I'm sure someone's way ahead of me on that), but no. The grace period for low-rep users has been removed to combat spam (particularly support number spam tipped us over the edge on that one)

Comment: There's no grace period for edits for users with <10 rep https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789. It's a relatively recent change https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/21789/26

Comment: "Relatively recent" - "May 13 2022" - I haven't been that active lately, does it show? Thanks @cigien. Feel free to post an answer, I've searched but couldn't find this change.

Comment: @CodeCaster everything is recent relative to the beginning of the universe... Also, I don't know about cigien but I use it to mean "I think I remember it from a couple of months ago but maybe it might be more. Not more than a year, though. Somewhere there" when I'm not exactly sure when something happened.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As mentioned in the [new user privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user), users with less than 10 rep cannot make edits that don't create a post revision history, i.e. they don't have a 5 minute grace period for edits.

> New users cannot:
>
> ...
>
> - make edits that don't create a post revision history - [read more about editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

This change was made relatively recently in 2022-05-13 (see [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445) when you feel some mechanism on the site behaves differently than what you're used to).

This change was made in response to a spam wave, where the spammers had stumbled upon the fact that changing a seemingly legitimate post into spam within the grace period would allow it to escape detection by [Smoke Detector](https://charcoal-se.org/smokey/). Smoke Detector is one of the primary defenses against spam and abuse on the network, so this was something that needed to be fixed. Removing grace period edits for new users essentially eliminated this loophole since most spammers don't have any reputation when they're posting content.

Comment: Ironically, SmokeDetector (SD) was changed such that it detects grace period edits at almost the same time as the SE feature change to eliminate grace period edits for users with < 10 reputation (the text for the pull request for SD was being composed when the SE feature rolled out). So, now, even if a spammer gets >= 10 reputation, the grace period edit will be detected by SmokeDetector.