# Edit grace period not applied

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits

I just posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75631663/1048572) and right after submitting it found a typo that I corrected. Usually, this should not create a new revision, but for some reason [it did](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75631663/revisions) - why?

I found [Was the 5 minute edit grace period removed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288557/1048572) and [5 minute edit grace period not applied?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420851/1048572) but these don't seem to apply here.

Comment: Most likely someone commented and deleted it right after that.

Comment: @Tom In the 35s between posting the answer and saving the edit? Seems unlikely to me. But a mod could certainly confirm.

Comment: @Bergi agree that it's unlikely for an answer posted 1+ hour after the question was asked to get an immediate attention...

Comment: Already [reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387164/478746) ([twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387167/478746)) and `status-reviewed`'d on MSE

Comment: @Brian Ah. As usual, I only searched on MSO and forgot MSE.

Comment: Confirmed as unintentional on the MSE site now https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387170/145673